# Replace one item in a chest

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am working on a chest menu. In the chest I have 2 full sets of armor. When someone clicks one part of the armor it must be replaced with enchanted armor.
I tried `/blockdata 6 11 -13 {Items:[0:{},1:{},2:{},3:{},4:{},5:{Slot:23b,id:minecraft:iron_boots,Count:1b}]}` which laced the item just in the 5th slot. I also tried `/blockdata 6 11 -13 {Items:[5:{Slot:23b,id:minecraft:iron_boots,Count:1b}]}` which was then changed in the command block to `[0:{...}]`.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `replaceitem` command. For example to replace the slot `23` with `iron_boots` the command should be:

```
/replaceitem block 6 11 -13 slot.container.24 iron_boots 1
```

[Click here for more info on `replaceitem`.](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#replaceitem)

Comment: @Zloutek1 No problem. Glad it helped! :D